# How to use .onDrag without implementing NSItemProviderWriting

Tags: swift, uikit, swiftui

I want to call `.onDrag` and pass it a custom object and I don't want to have to implement `NSItemProviderWriting` because it's complicated.

UIKit has a class called `UIDragItem` that has a property `localObject`. Is it possible to use this or an equivalent with SwiftUI?

Answer (score 3):

I added a `UUID` id to my object and created an `NSItemProvider` from that.

```
.onDrag {

    NSItemProvider(object: NSString(string: self.clip.id.uuidString))
}
```

Then I can locate the entity using this Id on a drop.

Even easier is to ignore the `NSItemProvider` stuff and pass a closure to a drop delegate...

```
.onDrag(of: [], delegate: ClipDropDelegate(f: { self.viewModel.changePosition(clip: self.clip) }))
```